# replace the clear:both with pseudo class

Tags: html, css, block

Previously, when I had floatings blocks, and i will stop the float, i used ;

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

But now, i'm solve this problem with pseudo class :

```
.last_floating_div:after {
 content: ""; 
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
```

I has always works perfectly. But today... It doesn't work... !
Look at this clear example : http://jsfiddle.net/YsueS/2/

I know my problem is a total beginner problem. I have sold this problem so many times... I really don't understand why it doesn't work here !

Many thanks all of you !

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/YsueS/3/

Comment: Thanks Josh, the result is perfect ! In this case, the solution of JoshC seems to be more lightweight, but I keep your solution for further needs :)

Comment: No problem! Overflow is the most basic and widely used way to achieve this. You can also use `overflow: auto` for absolute elements I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - you could clear it via an `:after` clearfix, however the most optimal, lightweight solution would just be to set `overflow:hidden` on the parent, achiving the desired effect with much less coding.

```
#mention {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JSuGN/)

To answer the question directly though, you should have applied the `:after` clearfix to `#mentions` - the parent, instead of the child.. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nqD3m/) it works.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` would be the best answer for older IE right?

Comment: Thank you ! You're right, in this case, overflow is really lightweight than pseudo class :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a #mention:after to do what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

```
#mention:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
#mention { display: inline-block; }

* html #mention{ height: 1%; } /* for older ie */
#mention { display: block; }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YsueS/8/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. Answers for genuine cross browser compatibility :) - @Jawad

Comment: But check my fiddle and do it practically to get a confirmation too. Thx for the +1 - @Jawad

Comment: cool @Nathan Lee. +1 to your question. There are only three things that you can do. Clearfix @ extra markup, Overflow: auto @ no support for old browsers, I forgot the third one.

Comment: I suggest some extra mark up for complete browser compatibility is an ideal way. - @Jawad

Comment: yeah but the fanatics for semantic web always have a good case against it. but you real question is why it does not work in your case?

Answer (score 1):

If you just add the `:after` to the id `mention` you will get the desired effect.

```
#mention:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YsueS/3/)